# Record the travel distance of the pointer throughout the day on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, logs, mouse

I am looking for a program for Microsoft Window that can record the travel distance of the pointer throughout the day.

Ideally, it should be able to distinguish between different inputs ( e.g., mouse 1, trackpad, head tracking device.)

Any price and license is fine.

Comment: very curious why you should need such a tool ?

Comment: @daredevil I am trying to minimize the use of computer mice.

Answer (score 3):

[Mousotron (free)](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/mousotron.html) might be suitable:

> Mousotron is a mouse and keyboard activity monitor and keeps statistics of your mileage. It's like an odometer or tripometer for your mouse cursor.
>   It calculates just how far your mouse cursor has traveled on your screen and how many times the mouse buttons were clicked. Also the number of keystrokes on your keyboard are counted.
>
> Mousotron keeps track of the following statistics :
>   - Distance traveled
>   - Left, middle and right button clicks
>   - Double clicks
>   - Mousewheel scrolls
>   - Cursor Speed
>   - Number of keystrokes
>   - X and Y Coordinates

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wish it was able to distinguish between different inputs.